# Using Hadoop through a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: hadoop, proxy

So our Hadoop cluster runs on some nodes and can only be accessed from these nodes. You SSH into them and do your work.

Since that is quite annoying, but (understandably) nobody will even go near trying to configure access control so that it may be usable from outside for some, I'm trying the next best thing, i.e. using SSH to run a SOCKS proxy into the cluster:

```
$ ssh -D localhost:10000 the.gateway cat
```

There are whispers of SOCKS support (naturally I haven't found any documentation), and apparently that goes into `core-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://reachable.from.behind.proxy:1234/</value></property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>reachable.from.behind.proxy:5678</value></property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.net.SocksSocketFactory</value></property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.socks.server</name>
  <value>localhost:10000</value></property>
```

Except `hadoop fs -ls /` still fails, without any mention of SOCKS.

Any tips?

---

I'm only trying to run jobs, not administer the cluster.
I only need to access HDFS and submit jobs, through SOCKS (it seems there's an entirely separate thing about using SSL/Proxies between the cluster nodes etc; I don't want that, my machine shouldn't be part of the cluster, just a client.)

Is there any useful documentation on that? To illustrate my failure to turn up anything useful: I found the configuration values by running the hadoop client through `strace -f` and checking out the configuration files it read.

Is there a description anywhere of which configuration values it even reacts to? (I have literally found zero reference documentation, just differently outdated tutorials, I hope I've been missing something?)

Is there a way to dump the configuration values it is actually using?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to make this work? are you hadoop v2 with YARN? I am able to access HDFS and YARN with the settings you have here, but the YARN job fails because nodes aren't able to talk to each other (presumably they are trying to do so through the socks proxy also). What error does `hadoop fs -ls` give?

Comment: no… I only ever used it via SSH, but stopped entirely soon after due to other issues with the cluster.

Answer (score 6):

The original code to implement this was added in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1822

But this article also notes that you have to change the socket class to SOCKS

http://rainerpeter.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/connect-to-hdfs-using-a-proxy/

with

`<property>
 <name>hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.net.SocksSocketFactory</value>
</property>`

Edit: Note that the properties go in different files:

1. fs.default.name and hadoop.socks.server and hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default needs to go into **core-site.xml**
2. mapred.job.tracker and mapred.job.tracker.http.address config needs to go into **mapred-site.xml** (for map-reduce config)

Comment: Hm, that is one of the properties I already had set, to no effect. I manually tunnelled both ports used instead though

Comment: I've looked further and into the source code and HDFS via SOCKS works reliably with the configuration above but not other services (eg hive) so it's not much use to me.