# Access HDFS in Remote Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Currently, I have a remote Hadoop cluster. When I try to access data in datanode through namenode, the namenode will redirect me to the datanode.
However, the returned domain name of datanode can only be recognized inside that cluster. Furthermore, I cannot revise `/etc/hosts` in client side.

Can I configure the namenode to redirect me with any IP or domain?
Where is the namenode used to record the domain to return?

Comment: hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip=false can help

Comment: Not sure I understand your last questions. The clients need to contact the datanodes directly. That's how data is read/written.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you need is a `Gateway` server (also called `EdgeNode`). There are several tutorial out there.

In your particular case your server holding the namenode will also hold the EdgeNode.

There are two particular projects to achieve this:

1. Using SOCKS proxy. [Using Hadoop through a SOCKS proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071320/using-hadoop-through-a-socks-proxy)
2. Using HTTPFS: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html